# Map an array of objects to a column of a datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, object, datatable

Is it possible to store an array of objects in a column of a datatable?

```
object[] arr1 = new object[] { "a", false, 100 };
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["Column1"] = arr1;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
// After
foreach (DataRow rowRead in dt.Rows)
{
    object[] result = rowRead["Column1"];
}
```

Comment: This smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1031060).  Can you explain _why_ you want to do this?  Is there a deeper question you are really trying to solve, or are you genuinely curious about how `DataTable` works?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: I have a ToolStrip of an application that was growing and growing ... Each option is retrieved from a datatable that has the allowed authorizations. I have started to migrate the entire application to small dll. In some of the cases when the winform was called, parameters were used. So I need the DLLs to be called in the cases that have parameters or not. Those parameters I need in a column of the datatable. If not possible, I will migrate the Datatable to a List <typeColumnsDataTable>

Comment: I too am curious why you'd want to do this. Have you thought about using a DataSet and two DataTables with some sort of key to match them up? If it were me I'd try to get away from the DataTable and just use a POCO with an array in it, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign a **set** to a **datatable** column.

*You can convert the set to a string and assign it to a column, and do the same operation in reverse to read the column.*

`string.Join (Separator, collection)` Converts an collection to a string.
You can assign its output to **DataTable** `column`.

```
object[] arr1 = new object[] { "a", false, 100 };
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["Column1"] = string.Join(",", arr1);
dt.Rows.Add(row);
// After
foreach (DataRow rowRead in dt.Rows)
{
   object[] result = (rowRead["Column1"].ToString().Split(',')).ToArray<object>();
}
```

Comment: I liked the idea for my project. I think it can work. The only thing I don't know why it happens to me is that row ["Column1"] = string.Join (",", arr1); I capitalize "False" F. Instead of "false".

Comment: Excuse me. If I just read the documentation and from bool to string the first letter is capitalized

Comment: Converts the components of an array or list into a string with row ["Column1"] = string.Join (",", arr1); . The first parameter is the value separator and the second parameter is the array or list